# Symfony $request->file->all() doesn't have all the attachments?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

I have an angularjs application that adds attachments to a formData and sends it to my symfony controller. To get the uploads and to loop over the multiple uploads from the post, i'm using:

$request->files->all();

and tried:

$request->files;

When i loop over the attachments, symfony is only returning 1 upload? When I check the payload from my Angular app, it shows 2+ files being sent? Shouldn't both of the files be in the Symfony filebag? The API documents show that it should be an array of the files.

Here is a test controller i have been using to try and display the names of the files being uploaded. So far it only shows the last file uploaded.

```
public function saveAttachment(Request $request) {
    $files = $request->files->all();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo $file->getClientOriginalName();
        echo "<br>";
    }
    exit;
}
```

I'm not using Symfony forms to generate my HTML, it is separate from the Symfony app.

Comment: I suggest that you might put in a call to render a twig template and then call `{{ dump(files) }}` in your twig to see what's in that $files array.

Comment: controller  code looks  fine - problem must be in view (or somewhere else  )